# Direct2D overwrite on existing content

Tags: c++, graphics, plot, render, direct2d

I am developing a "Plot XY" (like in [MatLAB](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/Images/xy_4_2_lg.png)) using Direct2D, where my requirement is, during the simulation (take about 5 - 10 minutes) I need to plot Y Values in a fixed X-axis. Since the X-Axis doesn't change, I need to plot the new Y-values on the fixed X-Axis without deleting the old Y-Values on the screen (BitMap or so).

The problem with the Direct2D is, every time 
Before drawing one dot, I need to

> pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

and
After plotting the dot, I need to

```
hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
```

Because of this, I'm losing the old values. Any suggestions how to approach this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to close this question, as the answer can be found here:
[Direct2D - preserve the existing content and overwrite the new values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860870/direct2d-preserve-the-existing-content-and-overwrite-the-new-values)